# In angularjs, grouping the checkbox and radio buttons

Tags: angularjs

Since I'm new to angularjs and hence asking the approach for this UI design in angularjs. I have two radio buttons and each radio button has corresponding container UI which has 3 checkboxes in it.

I have attached the screenshot for reference.[image]

When I click fruit, only fruits checkbox should be visible and when i click Vegetables, only vegetables checkbox should be visible.
[image]

I'm not sure how do it start.. using table or something else.
Small sample code would be fine for me to proceed

Thanks

Comment: there are sevearal approaches....for instance u can use ng-if and use ng-repeat on a list to display checkboxes and update the list on condition by ng-if...

Comment: It starts by reading the documentation (which does have "small sample code"), and then experimenting. https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms, https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bradio%5D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the filter in ng-repeat while displaying list:

```html
<div ng-app>
  <div ng-controller="TodoCtrl">
    <div class="radioGroup">
      <input type="radio" name="option" ng-model="selectedOption" value="Fruit"/>Fruit 
      <input type="radio" name="option" ng-model="selectedOption" value="Vegetable"/>Vegetable
    </div>

    <div class="checkboxgroup">
      <div class="list" ng-repeat="obj in checkboxlist | filter: {category: selectedOption}">
        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="obj.selected"/> 
        {{obj.name}}
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

function TodoCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.selectedOption = "Fruit";
  $scope.checkboxlist = [
    {name: 'Tomato', category: 'Vegetable'},
    {name: 'Potato', category: 'Vegetable'},
    {name: 'Onion', category: 'Vegetable'},
    {name: 'Apple', category: 'Fruit'},
    {name: 'Orange', category: 'Fruit'},
    {name: 'Mango', category: 'Fruit'}
  ]
}
```

You can view the demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/44724/).

Comment: sure .. let me try at my end